# TFPCustomHashTable constructor use 196613 constant. Why use this particular value?

Tags: freepascal

Following code is part of [contnrs](https://github.com/zamronypj/freepascal/blob/master/packages/fcl-base/src/contnrs.pp) unit of FreePascal

```
constructor TFPCustomHashTable.Create;
begin
  CreateWith(196613,@RSHash);
end;
```

I am curious about `196613`. I know it is hash table size. Is there any particular reason why this value is used?

In my test, constructor took about 3-4 ms to execute, which in my particular situation is not accepted. I suspect this is related to this constant value.

**Update:**

My question are:

- Why `196613` is chosen? Why not other prime number?
- Does it affect constructor call execution time?

Comment: Is your question about why 196613 was chosen? Or is your question related to the performance?

Comment: Both. Why `196613`? and does it affect constructor call performance?

Comment: One question at a time please here

Comment: An (initial) hash table size of 196613 may be a little large, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`196613` is one of the numbers being recommended for hash tables sizes (prime and far away from powers of two), for more info see e.g. https://planetmath.org/goodhashtableprimes.

It affects the constructor call execution time, yes. You can always construct `TFPCustomHashTable` using `CreateWith` and pass a size of your choice (any number is fine, as resizing algorithm checks for suitable sizes anyways) as well as your own hash function (or the pre-defined `RSHash`):

`MyHashTable:=TFPCustomHashTable.CreateWith(193,@RSHash);`

Keep in mind though, that resizing a hash table is an expensive operation as it requires to recalculate the hash function for all elements, so starting with a too small value is neither a good idea.